# How to stop displaying error when data inside text input was set like this: value={value} React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

React Hook Forms detect that I change the value of text input when I type something (onChange). But can it also detect the change if I enter data to the input by `value={value}`?

`const validator = register(name);`

I need something like

```
onValueSet={(e) => {
            validator.onChange(e);
          }}
```

I mean if I just set data by `value={value}` I get an error that this input is required. I don't want this error, because data was set by `value={value}`.

Here is my input:

```
<StyledInput
          name={name}
          maxLength={100}
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            validator.onChange(e);
          }}
        />
```

and my validation schema:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string()
      .required("required"),
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `reset` here and call it when you received your initial form data. I assume you're doing an api call and want to set the result to the form. You can do so with `useEffect`, watching when you're data has resolved and then reset the form with the actual values. This way you don't have to set the value via the `value` prop and let RHF manage the state of your inputs. You also don't need to set `name` prop, as RHF's `register` call returns this prop as well.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const { result } = useApiCall();
  const { register, reset } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(result)
  }, [result]);

  return (
   ...
    <StyledInput
      {...register('first_name')}
      maxLength={100}
    />
    ...
  )
}
```

Here is a little CodeSandbox demonstrating your use case:

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Reset Form (forked)]

Comment: I think that's it! Thank You a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an `onfocus` or `onkeyup` event and call the validation function there instead of `onChange` event.

```
<StyledInput
  name={name}
  maxLength={100}
  value={value}
  onfocus={(e) => {
    validator.onChange(e);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It's not that. The value is setting immediately after the page is loaded so ```validator.onChange(e);``` should run when the ```value={value} is setting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the validator when input changes, you can instead call your validator through the **onBlur** event. And I am not sure how you are using react-hook-form .. but the useForm hook has a config **mode** *(onChange | onBlur | onSubmit | onTouched | all = 'onSubmit')* on when to trigger the validation:

Comment: I am using onSubmit but it doesn't matter. I mean when the page is loaded f.e. in the first_name input will be set a value "Justin" by value={value}. validator won't handle it and he will still think that the input is empty. When I change onChange to onBlue I still need to click on the input and then click outside the input to not show the error

Comment: Now I understand your concern. Since you are using onChange event, and value already has data, it will be considered as the initial value and works as expected not to trigger the onChange event because there was no changes done on the initial value... I am suggesting you manually trigger you validator during component mount .. for functional component version of componentDidMount:

useEffect(() => { //trigger validator here on first mount }, []);